# value in cell return value up to max value in another cell and over max value in third cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a value in F4, I need G4 to display the value to a max value of 5000, and H4 to display the value of F4 less the max value of 5000. 
Right now I have this, but it doesn't give me a value in G if over 5000.

G  =IF(F4<=5000,F4,"")

H  =IF(F4>5000,F4-5000,"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In G4:

```
=MIN(F4,5000)
```

In H4:

```
=F4-G4
```

Comment: well now I feel super dumb :-)  Thanks so much for the simple solution!!

Comment: If it worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Should that be `=MAX(0, F4-G4)` in H4? (*'to display the value of F4 less the max value of 5000.'*)

Comment: @Jeeped If F4 is less than 5000 G4 will equal F4 and then F4-G4 will = 0.  If F4 is greater than 5000 Then G4 will equal 5000 and H4 will equal the remainder.

Comment: @ScottCraner - You're right of course. I wasn't thinking of the result from the first formula.

Comment: @Jeeped what's the phrase about a broken clock.  This is my first today so I get one more.